# how to recuperate the data from a QuerySet with django

Tags: django, python-2.7

I'm totally new with django and I'm trying to recuperate data from database and then send it to the template so that data will be displayed in a table.

I made a querySet and I got this response :

```
 <QuerySet [<name: Gen>,<name: Alen>]>
```

when I displayed in the template I had the same string in my table. I would like to display only the name ' Gen ' and Alen in the table

this is the table :

```
  <td> <ul> <li>{{teachers.name_list}} </li> </ul></td>
```

could you help me please ?

**Edit :**

this is in my model.py :

```
    def name_list(self):
        names= self.names.all()
        return u'%s' % (names)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate over it

```
<td>
    <ul>
    {% for name in teachers.names.all %}
        <li>{{ name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</td>
```

`teachers.name_list` will not work because it returns string, not list of names

Comment: @pietà fixed should work. changed `teachers.name_list` to `teachers.names.all`

Answer (score 0):

You are making things much more difficult than they need to be. There is no need to convert the list to a string in your `name_list` method: just return `names`.

Now you can iterate through in the template:

```
<ul>
{% for name in teachers.name_list %}
    <li>{{ name.first_name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

(You haven't shown the Name model, I'm assuming that it has a `first_name` field but you should replace that as appropriate.)